# Adding serial port Arduino

Tags: keyboard, arduino, port, arduino-uno

I am trying to make my Arduino behave like I keyboard. I was successful to some extend. Currently, on device manager my Arduino is recognised as a keyboard "HID Keyboard device"

Here are some steps I have completed :

Reprogram the firmware to behave like a keyboard.

But, when I open the Arduino complier, it says there is no port to connect to. It is grayed out.

Here is a tutorial I followed : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1unTKKGd8qs

Any tips on the serial port one?

Do not advice me to go to control panel and select devices and then pick arduino. My Arduino has to REPROGRAMMED to behave like a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must set right permissions. What is your OS?

Comment: Ок! And what is your IDE?